How to get event object from other event element click?
I have tried many times, and looked up a lot, but it still doesn't work. So I hope everyone can enlighten me.
I have:
$.fn.logicTuoi_tinhTuoi = (e) => {
    $('#tuoi').html($.fn.tinhTuoi())
    if (!~$('#tuoi').text().indexOf('Lỗi')){
        $.fn.fireWorks(e)
        $('#tuoi').effect('fade')
    }else $('#tuoi').effect('shake')
}
$('#divTinhTuoi').on('click', '#tinhtuoi', (e) => {
    $.fn.logicTuoi_tinhTuoi(e)
})
$(document).on('keypress', '#divTinhTuoi', (e) => {
    if (e.which == 13){
        $.fn.logicTuoi_tinhTuoi(e)
    }
})

The problem is that I cannot get the event from the #tinhtuoi click event when I press the Enter key. So I can't pass e from the onClick #tinhtuoi event to the $.fn.logicTuoi_tinhTuoi(e) function.

Link image if you cannot viewed: https://ibb.co/vcqjsPC
I really want to be able to get the Event from clicking this button from pressing the Enter key. But I don't know how or is there any better way to do this please suggest me. Will be appreciated. Thank you very much.
The click event is a button.

Link if you cannot viewd image: https://ibb.co/DM3HdXK
I want I can get the 'e' from the click event and pass it to the keypress event. But I don't know what to do?
I am using cdn anime.js 3.2.2, Jquery 3.7.1, Jquery ui 1.13.

Why would you need the event of the button? When the keypress happens there might not have been a click event on the button yet.
What are you trying to accomplish?

@Code Spirtit I'm very sorry that my question is a bit confusing. So I modified it a bit. Can you review the images in the link on the post?

The actual problem ist that you want to get the click event listener in the keypress handler on the first hand and not that your code is not working.
Why would you wanna do that? Obviously Click Event is not a keypress event. If you rely on data of the click event there are other ways to accomplish this but i still dont know what you actually want to do.

@CodeSpirit The problem is when I use the mouse, click that button, it takes out 'e' $(this), and I can do 'e.target.id' or in my $.fn.fireWorks(e) function have use:
pointerX = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX
pointerY = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY.
So when I use the keypress event on another html object, it will not be able to get the 'e' like when I use the mouse to click on that button. If you have any other solution please let me know. Thank you very much.

@CodeSpirit Maybe I described the problem a bit confusingly. And my sample language is Vietnamese. If possible, please visit https://giacmo.epizy.com/#MENU and you will see Button Age Calculator v1.0, When I click the mouse the AnimeJS animation works, but when I use the key Enter, it won't be able to get the 'e' like when I use Mouse and click on the button. Link Image: https://ibb.co/r7vVypT

You should refactor your fireworks function to accept the position and not the event. Nonetheless theres no mouse position on keypress so you have to get it beforehand on mousemove and then pass it on keypress.

// Store pointer position on mousemove
const mousePositon = {x: 0, y: 0};
$(window).on("mousemove", (e) => {
  Object.assign(mousePosition, {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY});
});

$.fn.logicTuoi_tinhTuoi = (position) => {
    $('#tuoi').html($.fn.tinhTuoi())
    if (!~$('#tuoi').text().indexOf('Lỗi')){
        $.fn.fireWorks(position)
        $('#tuoi').effect('fade')
    }else $('#tuoi').effect('shake')
};

$('#divTinhTuoi').on('click', '#tinhtuoi', (e) => {
    // OnClick pass click event mouse position
    $.fn.logicTuoi_tinhTuoi({x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY})
})
$(document).on('keypress', '#divTinhTuoi', (e) => {
    if (e.which == 13){
        // Pass last mouse position
        $.fn.logicTuoi_tinhTuoi(mousePosition)
    }
})



Why Object.assign instead of just mousePositon.x = e.clientX?

Matter of style

Just call the button's click event with no parameter; $('#divTinhTuoi').click()
Javascript will provide the button's event object to the event handler
The result will be that when you press the Enter key, it will be as if the button was clicked.
$.fn.logicTuoi_tinhTuoi = (e) => {
    $('#tuoi').html($.fn.tinhTuoi())
    if (!~$('#tuoi').text().indexOf('Lỗi')){
        $.fn.fireWorks(e)
        $('#tuoi').effect('fade')
    }else $('#tuoi').effect('shake')
}
$('#divTinhTuoi').on('click', '#tinhtuoi', (e) => {
    $.fn.logicTuoi_tinhTuoi(e)
})
$(document).on('keypress', '#divTinhTuoi', (e) => {
    if (e.which == 13){
        // Javascript will provide the button's event object to the event handler
        $('#divTinhTuoi').click()
    }
})

